# Facebook Ignore Graph API Page Posts Connection - Ignore Replies & Comments? Story vs Message

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

I'm pulling page posts from the Graph API, but I would like to ignore comments or replies.

So for instance:

```
{
"id": "115673336230_10151050684306231", 
"from": {
"name": "New York Jets", 
"category": "Professional sports team", 
"id": "115673336230"
 }, 
"story": "\"Well said, Michael. We know our...\" on [User's name removed]'s post on New York Jets's wall.", 
"story_tags": {
"40": [
  {
    "id": ----------, 
    "name": ------------, 
    "offset": 40, 
    "length": 15, 
    "type": "user"
  }
]
}, 
"type": "status", 
"created_time": "2012-09-27T13:39:55+0000", 
"updated_time": "2012-09-27T13:39:55+0000", 
"comments": {
"count": 0
}
}`
```

There doesn't seem to be any piece of this response that I can use to filter a reply like this out other than the 'on User's Name post' bit in the story field.

I've noticed that all of the replies to comments appear without `message` data and with `story` data, but from the docs its unclear if this would be a reliable data point to filter against.

Is there a way to ignore comments/replies in the Page posts connection? Do all Page Posts (non comment replies) have data in the `message` field and never in the `story` field? That is, can I reliably ignore 'posts' that have no `message`? That have a `story`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want more powerful filtering, you should look at querying the [stream table with FQL](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/stream/).

The `type` field allows you to filter out posts based on what they are. Adding `AND type != 247` will exclude comments from the data returned.

There might be a way to do this using the API by requesting the `status_type` field, but then you'll have to also manually request all other fields you want to display, and you'll still end up filtering them in your script.

Comment: Following up- Pretty disappointed with FQL `type` field/filter. A bunch of the posts I wanted to filter out are returned with `"type": nil`, and `type != nil` FQL returns an error.

Comment: You can filter those out with `AND type > 0`.